# <data> tag for tmx file

Tags: c, xml

What is stored in the data tag of of a tmx file such as the following

```
<data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
 H4sIAAAAAAAAA+3YIQ6AMAwF0AEKEATwSO5/RCoRmGHY2BMvaVLzRb/pkVI6gOZ0oQ9DAVlynbd5DFOYH3Y1WcMW9gKytGbJ8HXWFtXaaQAAAAAA/s8Pm1xuBvLpDW9ciGmfRhAnAAA=
</data>
```

Also if this is key info, how is it read or extracted using c ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like binary octet data that has been compressed using [gzip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) and then encoded in [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) to make it XML-safe. Implementations for both should be easy to obtain, though I don't know enough C libraries to recommend one.

Comment: Thanks. I found an export setting on the application which creates the tmx file and it can be set to XML, so I have determined what the data is. Now I wonder what the reason for zipping the data is., purely for size, if there is even a difference in file size.

Comment: @Helium3 - Base64 encoding increases the size of the data (as it sticks to a range of octets that are "safe" for textual data); so it is often a good idea to offset this cost by compressing the data beforehand.

Comment: What would be the benefits of outputting this data rather than plain XML?

Comment: @Helium3 - no idea (if it can be represented as XML, it seems counter-productive) - I don't know anything about this format. But Base64 is the standard way of attaching binary data to an XML payload when it can't be represented as text (e.g. a graphic or executable).